# Why CAN trace doesn't display message name even if the message is defined in the dbc? Can you figure out some of the reasons behind it?

Tags: canoe

I have few CAN messages running in CAN trace of CANoe. I wanted to identify them from rest of the messages, so I add them in the DBC, but I still do not see the message name being displayed on the trace.
What could be the possible reason behind it?

[example: message 10000x in the trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLDjO.jpg)
[same message defined in the dbc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYRnn.jpg)

Comment: Please show some cases which you have tried. Without any information, it is not possible to help you.
Anyways, one possible reason is, you have added the wrong IDs in the DBC.

Comment: Thanks Shyam for your comment. I have added two screenshots of a message with ID 10000x, which I was trying to see its name on trace but it doesn't even after I have added it in the dbc. Please let me know if you can find something on this. Thank you.

Comment: Is the dbc added to CAN2?

Comment: @M.Spiller, you are right, I didn't had that in my mind. Actually I did add CAN2 in simulation because it was used just to listen to another bus. That solves my question Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved. I have to add a CAN2 in the simulation and add the same dbc to it.
Thanks to M.Spiller for solving. Also thanks to Shyam for actively giving feedbacks.